# Using collapsible with extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I am trying to make one of my panels in ExtJS4 collapsible. When I use "collapsible: true" the panel is collapsible when my application is running.  But if I collapse the panel it disappears so I can't uncollapse it.

I am not sure what needs to surround my panel or be directly above it.  I have tried using sample code:

```
{
region: 'north',
collapsible: false,
title: 'North',
split: true,
height: 100,
minHeight: 60,
html: 'north'
},
```

That works when I add it to my viewport to be at the top of the webpage.  But when I position it to be in the location I want it on the page I can collapse it but it then dissappears.  Can anyone let me know whatwould cause it to dissappear when collapsed?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it based off of [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?149446-Rendering-panel-collapsed-makes-it-disappear). Basically, make sure you have the rightt layout config specified on the panel your having trouble with, something like `layout: 'fit'`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Geronimo's answer, it is sometimes not enough to set the layout on the panel itself. In that case try wrapping your panel in another one with layout `fit`. Instead of

```
{
  xtype: 'mypanel',
  title: 'my little panel',
  collapsible: true,
  ...
}
```

do this:

```
{
  xtype: 'panel',
  title: 'my little panel', // Pull certain configs up to the wrapper panel,
  collapsible: true,        // like title and collapsible
  layout: 'fit',
  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'mypanel',
      title: undefined,     // Make sure there is not another title bar
      border: false,        // We don't want another border
      ...
    } 
  ]
}
```

Not nice but so far, I couldn't find a better solution and it did work in two different situations for me already.